# How do I use bash to selectively remove newlines?

Tags: bash, file-io, sed, newline

I have a server.log file with stacktraces that are written like this:

```
timestamp texttexttexttext \n
  at texttexttexttext\n
  at texttexttexttext\n
  at texttexttexttext\n
caused by texttexttexttext\n
  at texttexttexttext\n
  at texttexttexttext\n
  at texttexttexttext\n
  at texttexttexttext\n
```

as well as warnings/information written like this with all information in one line:

```
timestamp texttexttexttexttext \n
```

I want to parse the log file so that the only newline characters are the one's before the timestamps; that way the stacktraces are all one line and I can loop through it all later and only need to echo once to show the entire stacktrace. Basically I want the big stacktraces to look like this:

```
timestamp texttexttexttext
  at texttexttexttext
  at texttexttexttext
  at texttexttexttext
caused by texttexttexttext
  at texttexttexttext
  at texttexttexttext
  at texttexttexttext
  at texttexttexttext\n
```

I have tried to loop through the lines and if it starts with a timestamp, I add a newline before it and if it doesn't start with a timestamp, I use sed to replace the newline with a space. Below is the loop: the comments show me trying to put it all in a string to loop through it later, but I also tried putting it all in a file to go through later.

```
for x in "$(cat tempFile.txt)" 
do
    if [[ ! $x =~ [0-2][0-9](:+).* ]]
    then
        #STRINGBUILDER+=`printf "%s" $x | sed 's/"$NL"/" "/'`
        printf "%s" $x | sed 's/$'\n'/" "/' > parsed.txt
    else
        #STRINGBUILDER+=`printf "\n%s" $x`
        printf "\n%s" $x > parsed.txt
    fi
done
```

However, no matter how I loop through the file later, the newlines still seem to be there. How do I get rid of them?

Comment: I think your message is confusing with the presence of the `\n`s in your post. I hope your files don't have those characters explicitly in them.

Comment: @RSahu You're right, they aren't explicitly in the file, I just used them to help visualize where the newlines are exactly.

Comment: Can you post the output that you would like to get from the input?

Comment: What format is the timestamp ?

Comment: @Jidder The format is HH:MM:SS, so I used ^[0-2][0-9]:+ based on the feedback here –  user3688447 16 mins ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awk statement should work.

```
awk 'BEGIN {ORS=""};!/[1-2][1-9]/ {print} /[1-2][1-9]/{printf("\n%s",$0)}' tempFile.txt > parsed.txt;
```

How it works:

```
BEGIN {ORS=""}
```

Sets Output Record Separator to nothing so no newlines are printed.

```
!/[1-2][1-9]/ {print}
```

If it isnt a timestamp line (you can add more regex if you want. I didnt know the format) then print the line.

```
/[1-2][1-9]/{printf("\n%s",$0)}'
```

If it is a timestamp line then print a newline then the line

Answer (score 1):

The specific problem you're hitting is that there's only one argument in the loop: the entire file content.  That's because `"$(cat tempFile.txt)"` is quoted, so it gets assigned entirely to the variable `$x`.

Here's some (untested) code that should work, though I'd have to question the regex as well... it's not anchored, so the trailing `.*` is meaningless...

```
if read line; then
  while read next_line; do
    if [[ $next_line =~ [0-2][0-9]: ]]; then
        echo "$line"
    else
        echo -n "$line "
    fi
    line=$next_line
  done
  echo "$line"
fi < tempFile.txt > parsed.txt
```

Comment: That makes sense; problem was I was confused about how quotes were functioning there.

Comment: @user3688447 - you were also confused about redirection.  Review `>` vs `>>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to construct a string from the file and `echo` the string with the desired line format, you could do it like this:

```
str=""
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^[0-2][0-9]:+ ]]; then
        string+="$line"
    else
        string+="${line/\\n/\ }"
    fi
done < file
echo -en "$string\n"
```

The `.*` is unnecessary if you know the timestamp will be at the start of the line.  You could just prepend your regular expression with `^`.  Parentheses are only needed to enclose regex in Bash if you wish to access the `BASH_REMATCH` builtin array variable.

Comment: I'll try this way too; thanks for clarifying how to anchor the regex. It's my first time using them.